# Android: Can I wait in the previous Activity until next Activity is fully loaded?

Tags: android, android-activity, loading

I have 2 Activities.
First one is a list view and when i choose one, detail information Activity is opened.
Second one requires complicated loading process along with ViewPager.

The problem is that there are too many data to load & progress(includes Google Map data) and it makes my beginning animation's FPS terribly laggy, which is not good at all.

I decided to wait in the first Activity screen with central progress circle until second one is fully loaded.
How can I request Android to 'pre-parse' another Activity before being displayed?

Comment: Why not use Fragments?

Comment: you can use async task for that

Comment: Use async task and wait and show progress dialog until activity gets load

Comment: @cricket_007 I use FragmentPagerAdapter in the second one... But how can it helps what i'm facing?

Comment: @Amy If I use AsyncTask to load data, I think I should call setContentView() from 2nd and call AsyncTask. That will cause my screen to change to 2nd one.

Comment: in this case show Progress dialog instead

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is after clicking on an item in the listview (first activity) start an asynctask to fetch your data. Then this task is complete, start your second activity passing a bundle with the data previouly fetched

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but there are 2 problems; First there are too many data to put~get with bundle. Second GoogleMapFragment in 2nd Activity is the main reason of lags, but i cannot initialize in 1st and pass it to 2nd.

Comment: What kind of data are you fetching? Cannot Parcelable do the job ? What is the animation in your second activity ?

Comment: I'm fetching data from server and there is no limit in quantity because there are some lists. And I need my location and target location, and Google Map Fragment for displaying it. Opening Animation duration is about 2 sec.